# MySQL regular expression issue

Tags: mysql, expression

I have a varchar column "category" with several values:

```
1.1
1.1.1
2.1
2.2.2
3.1.2.1
```

Now I want to select all columns with only one "." (dot) in it's value.
But "...WHERE `category` regexp '[.]{1}'..." does not work, even if I escape the "." with a backslash.

Thanks in advance.
Matty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `like`:

```
where category like '%.%' and category not like '%.%.%'
```